# Read a path to a folder from a Excel-Workbook cell using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following VBA-code

```
Dim directory As String, fileName As String
directory = "C:\User\Work\scorix\test_excel\"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")
```

now I would like to change the code so that I would be able to read the path from a given Excel-Workbook cell and then build the `fileName`. 
If I try

```
directory = Worksheets("Summary").Range("B2").Value
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")
```

it dose not work. It means at the end of day `directory` is empty and therefore `fileName`  is empty.
In the next step I tried

```
  With ThisWorkbook
    directory = Sheets("Summary").Range("B2").Value
  End With
```

it works! (But, why?, probably I did not understand the [definition of With](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wc500chb.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)) 
However, in the next step

```
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")
```

`filename` is still empty. I tried everything with `ActiveSheet` however, without success!

Comment: I don't see nay thing wrong with above codes, i verified locally as well. Are you sure of having excel files in directory, you are referring? Does your B2 cell have directory path mentioned correctly? please check it

Comment: Your code works as expected for me as well. The problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: Check if there is an \ at the end of directory, if not add it. `fileName = Dir(directory & "\*.xl??")`

Comment: @VincentG your hint was the solution '\' thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

seems to me those errors occur rather arbitrary, which in my experience can happen when working with several worksheets simultaniously. Maybe replacing

```
directory = Worksheets("Summary").Range("B2").Value
```

with

```
directory = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Range("B2").Value
```

or alternatively (what is what i prefer to working with a range)

```
directory = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Summary").Cells(2, 2).Value
```

or alternatively

```
With ThisWorkbook
    ' notice the dot in Front of "worksheets"
    directory = .Worksheets("Summary").Range("B2").Value
End With
```

fixes things.

Another situational approach might be to name your Sheet-objects in the VBA-Editor (edit the (Name) property in the property window).

Hope that helps.

P.S.
Since you use the Dir()-Function, I trust you know that in order to get the 2nd+ File, you have to call it repeatedly (maybe in a loop) without supplying a directory.

Answer (score 1):

dir returns the first file in the path\pattern 
to recurse you need to do DIR("") pass an empty string

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
directory = Worksheets("Summary").Range("B2").Value
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")
```

there is nothing wrong with this code u might be writing the name of the worksheet wrong maybe?

```
 With ThisWorkbook
   directory = Sheets("Summary").Range("B2").Value
 End With
```

Don't forget about using "." before "sheets" when you are using with statements

```
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")
```

The main reason this code didn't work is propably because there are more than one files that ends with "*.xl??" in that folder

Comment: Dir(path) will always return the first file that matches the pattern. 

So, while it might not yield the result desired by the OP, it will return a string, if there are one or more files matching the search pattern